# Transfer array from one file to another in Node JS whenever the route called

Tags: arrays, node.js, express, mean-stack, mean

fruits.js

```
exports.fruitsList = async(req,res)=> {
  var fruit1 = req.body.fruit1;
  var fruit2 = req.body.fruit2; 
  var fruitsArray = [fruit1, fruit2];
  exports.fruitsArray = fruitsArray; // How do i export this array in to main.js file whenever this method called
}
```

main.js

```
var fruitsarray = require('./fruits.js').fruitsArray;
console.log(fruitsarray);
```

routes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var controller = require('./fruits');
router.post('/fruitslink', function (req, res) {
  controller.fruitsList(req, res);
});
```

How do I export fruitsArray into main.js file whenever this "fruitslink" route called ?

Comment: Where do you call the `fruitsList` method?

Comment: @Geshode Updated code, please check